# Difficult cast with int64 and int32 pointers

Tags: pointers, casting, int, memory-address

I have `int64_t value1; int32_t value2;`. Then I have `*(int32_t*)&value1 = value2;`

Could you please describe what `*(int32_t*)&value1` mean? Does it mean "the lowest 32 bits of value1" so `*(int32_t*)&value1 = value2;` means "the first 32 bits of value1 are replaced with those of value2"?

Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: It's about endianness. There were so many questions about this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is going to depend on the byte-order of the machine it runs on. It is pretty poor practice. 
On a little endian system, which is most Intel hardware, the lowest order byte is first, so the 32 bit SIGNED value will be written to the lower 32 bits of the 64 bit integer. On a big endian system, it would be written to the high order bits.

note that the int is signed. If value2 is a negative value, the resulting 64bit number will not be negative (unless it was already negative).

It also won't change the high order bits of the 64bit int.

I'd say...don't do that?

EDIT
To more directly answer your question, yes, you are right, depending on what you mean by the "first 32 bits". First in whatever order the platform uses, yes.

```
&value1 -> will give the address of value1
(int32_t*)&value1 -> tells the compiler to treat the address of value1 as a pointer to an int32_t
*(int32_t*)&value1 -> then dereference the pointer, so assigning to this will put the assigned value into the address of value1 as if it were an int32_t.
```